# Unable to index into an array to turn it into a hash table

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I am trying to convert an array into a hashtable but I keep getting this error

Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.

I have searched everywhere and could not find others having the same problem.

My code:

```
[array]$compArray = $ds3 | select -Property DeviceName, IP_Address

$DeviceHashtable = @{}
$compArray[0][0]
for ($i=0;$i -lt $compArray.length;$i++)
    {
    $1=[string]$compArray[0][$i];
    $2=[string]$compArray[1][$i];
    $DeviceHashTable.add("$1", "$2")
    }
```

$ds3 is a system.data.datatable object
and if I do $compArray | display-table all the data I want is there.
Any help is  appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$compArray = $ds3 | select -Property DeviceName, IP_Address
$DeviceHashtable = @{}
$compArray | %  {  $DeviceHashtable.add( $_.DeviceName, $_.IP_Address )}
```

Comment: Thank-you, that worked perfectly. The % sign is saying do X as many times as you can correct?

Comment: %  is the alias for foreach-object cmdlet. Try: get-help foreach-obeject -full to read about it! Glad to help